# YouTube resumable upload file from another server using php

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth

I am using the following php sample code to upload videos to youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads

However, I need to look into the possibility to upload a file stored in a another server. For instance, the path to the video as in the example above

```
$videoPath = "/path/to/file.mp4";
```

to be replace with something similar to

```
$videoPath = "http://142.4.1.45/myvideos/tutorials/video_1.mp4";
```

Is this possible? I tried doing it, but get a timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to write the video file in to the server, then use that path to upload to YouTube.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://142.4.1.45/myvideos/tutorials/video_1.mp4');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
raw = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$videoPath = '/tmp/video_1.mp4';
$fp = fopen($videoPath, 'x');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, according to the flow of your code uploading to youtube will be executed after fclose()? will there be a confilct with fwrite() and $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk); when uploading a large file?